# Jquery Mobile Erro Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Quando tento chamar a biblioteca Jquery Mobile (Usando [CDN](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js) ou o próprio código baixado no site [Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Recebo o seguinte erro no console do Browser (Chrome e Firefox):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Portanto, não consigo utilizar nada do Jquery Mobile.
Alguém sabe algo que ajude a resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deverá existir uma compatibilidade entre a versão do jquery e do jquery mobile.

Este é um exemplo da última versão.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Mais informações:

```
http://jquerymobile.com/download/
```